# What is the accurate way to read/download a file from the server (in Java)?

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, client-server, bufferedreader

In my client-server application I have used a command (`GET filename`)to download a file into the client side. I have used the build in `read()` method to read the file. My teachers said it's not a very good practice to implement this `read` method. The reason is either it doesn't tell how exactly the file is reading from the server or it somehow is not able to download dynamic (large) file size. But at the moment I see that it's working fine. Since I am still in intermediate level in java, I need to learn the best way to do this job. How it could be improved in coding? That is I want to improve the `while looping` part in ClientSide.

I have pasted the relevent code:

ClientSide:

```
                         ............
                         ............
                        if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                        File file = new File(request.substring(4));
                        is = socket.getInputStream();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                        int bytesReceived = 0;

                        while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer)) >=0) {
                            //while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer))>=buffer) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                        }
                        request = "";
                        fos.close();
                        is.close();
                    }
                       .................
                       .................
```

ServerSide:

```
                          .................
                          .................
else if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                        System.out.println("");
                        String filename = request.substring(4);
                        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                        File[] files = file.listFiles();

                        if (fileExists(files, filename)) {
                            file = new File(filename);
                            int fileSize = (int) file.length();
                            outputToClient.print("Status OK\r\n"
                                    + "Size " + fileSize + "KB" + "\r\n"
                                    + "\r\n"
                                    + "File " + filename + " Download was successfully\r\n");
                            outputToClient.flush();
                            // reading files
                            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                            os = socket.getOutputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[2^7-1];
                            int bytesRead = 0;
                            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer))!= -1) {
                                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            os.close();
                            fis.close();
                        } else {
                            outputToClient.print("Status 400\r\n"
                                    + "File " + filename + " not found\r\n"
                                    + "\r\n");
                            outputToClient.flush();
                        }
                    }
                    outputToClient.flush();
                }
                           .................
                           .................
```

Comment: Have u searched this question on google?

Comment: Ranjeet, ya. but haven't found any relevent information. If you have better suggestion please help me, specially in while loop in client side.

Comment: r u aware how client-server communication handled in java?

Comment: Ranjeet, yes. I am .

Comment: Your  code is looking good for me but u knw reason why ur teacher said like this..Have u asked reason

Comment: We can't really help you address your teacher's criticism without knowing what it actually was.  Ask him or her and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consume the rest of the HTTP response headers, by reading until you get a blank line, if you haven't already done that.

Apart from that, your code looks fine to me, except that I would use a much bigger buffer than 127, at least 8192, possibly a multiple of that.

Ask your teacher what (on earth) he's talking about.

Comment: EJP, thank you for your concern.  He meant not to have a built in read method, rather I should create a method manually for reading.

Comment: Eh? You have to call the built-in read() method sooner or later. The part about not being 'able to download large (dynamic) file sizes' is BS too. I fail to see the point. Tell him to read my book.

Comment: EJP, very good. you are right. But I am frustrated about this issue. I really don't know how the looping can be done in an alternative way. I think that's the thing my teacher want. ok, I need your book.

Comment: Pitt, *Fundamental Networking in Java,* Springer 2005 (?). There are any number of ways to code the copy loop, but I have always preferred the way you did it. I hope your teacher has a somewat higher-level concern than how to write the loop, but I have no idea what it could be. Sooner or later you still have to write this loop, or another form of it. NB the claim that 'it doesn't tell exactly how the file is reading from the server' is BS as well, or meaningless, unless he is talking about some form of progress indicator, which is easy enough to build *into* this loop.